How to use a custom Activity with AndroidView in Jetpack Compose?
I am building a Jetpack Compose application and need to extend an Activity (e.g., BrightcovePlayer) to handle specific logic and states. My goal is to integrate this custom Activity into a Jetpack Compose screen using AndroidView.
For example, I want to create a class that extends an Activity, manage its states and lifecycle from there, and then embed its functionality into my Compose-based UI. How can I properly achieve this with AndroidView?
Here's an outline of what I am trying to do:

Extend a custom Activity. Use it with AndroidView in a Compose
screen. Ensure lifecycle and state management works correctly within
the Compose framework.

Any guidance, examples, or best practices would be greatly appreciated!

If you want to use multiple Activities in your app you can just add your Activity containing BrightcovePlayer to the navigation graph

My entire application is based on a single activity. Isn't there a way to achieve this using only Compose?
